# Cannot become root inside aptitude

Tags: aptitude

### Cannot become root within aptitude

If you install the aptitude and invoke with

```
aptitude
```

you cannot become root and will get this error message:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get root access after e.g. you press <kbd>u</kbd> (update the package list) you have to add `aptitude::Get-Root-Command "sudo:/usr/bin/sudo";` to your `~/.aptitude/config` file.

Type these commands in your shell

```
mkdir -v ~/.aptitude
echo 'aptitude::Get-Root-Command "sudo:/usr/bin/sudo";' >> ~/.aptitude/config
```

The default configuration is the `su` command.

More settings and configuration options can be found in the [aptitude manual](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/aptitude/ch02s05s05.en.html).